# What can we say about $\mathbb{E} \left(\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^N X_i}\right)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

Let $X_i \sim \exp(\lambda)$ for $i= 1, ..., N$ and i.i.d. Hence $\mathbb{E}(X_i) = \frac{1}{\lambda}$. What can we say about $\mathbb{E} \left(\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^N X_i}\right)$?

I think that $\sum_{i=1}^N X_i \sim \exp(\lambda)$, but I am not sure we can say $\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^N X_i} \sim \exp(\lambda)$

Comment: are the $X_i$, $I=1.\ldots,N$ independent?

Comment: Yes, they are I.I.D

Comment: @JDoe: the sum of iid exponentials is a Gamma distribution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655302/gamma-distribution-out-of-sum-of-exponential-random-variables). That does not solve your problem just yet, but it corrects your first conjecture.

Comment: It follows an inverse Gamma distribution. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution

Comment: I am not familiar with the Gamma distribution yet. Are you up to build a full answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inverse of sum of exponential random variables (mean and variance)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3239064/inverse-of-sum-of-exponential-random-variables-mean-and-variance)